# How would I convert a ulong data type input to a string for verbal number output?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, data-conversion

I am currently trying to make an application in C# that takes a `ulong` number input and outputs the verbal representation of the number (i.e. 12 to "twelve", 45238 to "forty five thousand two hundred thirty eight", etc.) and I'd like for it to be able to pass `uLong.MaxValue`.

I am new to programming and really struggling with the concept. I've tried to implement Lists and `StringBuilder` earlier because I figured they could be useful, but I could not figure it out. I am trying to adapt the base code so that it works for `ulong` data types but I get the following errors:

> error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
> properties: 'Math.Abs(decimal)' and 'Math.Abs(float)' error CS1503:
> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'ulong'

Here is the base code:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Numerics;

namespace NumberToText
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string ConvertToText(ulong number)
        {
            if (number == 0)
            return "zero";

        if (number < 0)
            return "minus " + ConvertToText(Math.Abs(number));

        string words = "";

        if ((number / 1000000) > 0)
        {
            words += ConvertToText(number / 1000000) + " million ";
            number %= 1000000;
        }

        if ((number / 1000) > 0)
        {
            words += ConvertToText(number / 1000) + " thousand ";
            number %= 1000;
        }

        if ((number / 100) > 0)
        {
            words += ConvertToText(number / 100) + " hundred ";
            number %= 100;
        }

        if (number > 0)
        {
            if (words != "")
                words += "and ";

            var units = new[] 
            { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };
            var tens = new[] 
            { "zero", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

            if (number < 20)
                words += units[number];
            else
            {
                words += tens[number / 10];
                if ((number % 10) > 0)
                    words += "-" + units[number % 10];
            }
        }

        return words;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Write("Enter a number: ");
            var number = ReadLine();

            ConvertToText(number);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To convert a `string` to a ulong, you should use `ulong result = ulong.Parse(stringInput)` (unless you aren't certain that the string is a number, in which case `TryParse` would be a better choice).

Comment: side note: `ulong` is always positive, so there is no reason for `if (number < 0)`. Also, you can make the code more readable with `1_000_000` instead of `1000000`

Comment: And just complementing what @RufusL said, `Console.ReadLine();` returns a string, so you have to convert it to ulong first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Math.Abs(decimal)' and 'Math.Abs(float)'

The first error is telling you that there is no overload for `Abs` which takes a `ulong` argument, and it's ambiguous which candidates it should use (either `decimal` or `float`).

To resolve this, you must cast the value yourself. Also note that you then have to cast the result of `Abs` back to `ulong` before passing the result to your method:

```
if (number < 0)
    return "minus " + ConvertToText((ulong) Math.Abs((decimal) number));
```

However it should be pointed out that a `ulong` is an *unsigned* long, which means it will never be negative and therefore this check is not needed.

---

> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'ulong'

The second error is telling you that there is no implicit conversion from `string` to `ulong`. In order to resolve this, we can use `ulong.Parse` or `ulong.TryParse`. Since the input is not guaranteed to be a valid `ulong`, we should use `TryParse` so we can add some error handling and let the user try again if they entered invalid input.

`TryParse` takes a string parameter and an `out` parameter that will be set to the converted value, and it returns a `bool` that indicates if the conversion was successful. So we can implement it something like:

```
Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
var input = Console.ReadLine();

ulong number;

while (!ulong.TryParse(input, out number))
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.Write("Invalid input, please try again: ");
    Console.ResetColor();
    input = Console.ReadLine();
}

string result = ConvertToText(number);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight! That helped a lot. Now the application checks if it is a valid input, but I am not sure what I need to write to bring back `words` from the ConvertToText function for output within the main function. I feel like I am using parameters wrong since `words` does not exist in the current context.

Comment: `words` is returned from your method, so you simply assign the result of the method call to a variable, or output it directly. I updated the answer with a sample.